# free symptoms/disease database

Tags: android, database, medical

I'm willing to make an android app in Medical app. the app searches in a database of symptoms to tell the user what disease it is.

Can anybody tell me where I can find this database for free? thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow community is here to help resolve problems you are facing with your code and not a Search engine. Google search may helps you better find what you are looking for.

Learn how to ask [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check [this](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/api/), there is a list of available databases. F.e. first "AIDSinfo" use RESTful api for accessing data.

Comment: thanks! but no database for general diseases.

Comment: @yanisb how about item "MedlinePlus Connect"? On their site you can find meny diseases grouped. "For developers": https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/fordevelopers.html

Comment: good one. but not what I wanted, I want a db where you enter symptoms(many), the db returns possible disease. if there is no such db online, any pdf or anything else legal and official and free to use that provide such informations will do the trick for me!. anyway thank you very much Niobij.

Comment: anything like that is good for me:[link](http://www.ashanet.org/seattle/events/tsunamirelief/resources/reliefworkers-english.pdf)

Comment: looks like the link you gave me is good Niobij! many thanks!!!